# device.platform return 'device is not defined' on cordova project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've a problem that happens randomly when I run my cordova android application. Basically the "device" sometime is null and sometime not. I dunno why it happens, this is the first portion of my code:

**app.js**

```
app = {

    // deviceready Event Handler
    onDeviceReady: function() {

        try
        {           
            var devicePlatform = device.platform;
            var deviceVersion = device.version;     
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert("Error: "+e)
        }

        ....
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
....
    </div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/openfb.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
            $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = true;
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "fade";
            $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;   
        });

        // init application
        $(window).load(function() {
            $(document).bind('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady());   
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The device plugin was outdated so I obtained the new version, 0.3.0 but the bug is still there. Any hints?

Comment: the latest version is 1.1.0, not 0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Your app should work on real phone, not on emulator.

I think you run app only on your chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Please try binding a listener

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
    element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}
```

See more at [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html)

Hope this helps !

Cheers !